# How to merge many tsv.gz files efficiently

Tags: python, unix, pyspark, bigdata

I have ~3000 files each around 1GB - 1.5GB all with the same column format. I want to merge these files into one file but the way I've coded this merge at the moment, if I applied it to my total list of ~3000 files, it would try to produce a 3000-4000GB file.

What are the best practices when merging many files and handling large data like this? Is there a way to merge the files but reduce the size.

I am using unix to purposely avoid reading in the files one by one but is there potentially a better solution with python using something like PySpark?

Here is the code I'm testing a few files with currently:

```
#!/bin/bash

output_file="merged.tsv"
stats_dir="home/stats"

# Initialize merged file with contents of the first file (excluding the header)
first_file=$(ls "$stats_dir"/*.tsv.gz | head -n 1)
gzip -dc "$first_file" | sed '1d' > "$output_file"

# Concatenate the contents of all tsv.gz files (excluding the header) into the merged file
for file in "$stats_dir"/*.tsv.gz; do
  if [ "$file" != "$first_file" ]; then
    gzip -dc "$file" | sed '1d' >> "$output_file"
  fi
done

gzip "$output_file"

echo "Merge and compression complete!"
```

I've also looked at something with PySpark, because I plan on using it for several further filtering steps with the merged file, but I assume the issue  then becomes that the 3k GB of memory is needed for the code rather than storage:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("MergeFiles").getOrCreate()

output_file="merged.tsv"
stats_dir="home/stats"

# Read the files into a DataFrame
df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "\t").csv(f"{stats_dir}/*.tsv.gz")

df = df.filter(df["p-value"] <= 5E-8)

# Write the merged DataFrame as Parquet files with Snappy compression
df.write.parquet(output_file, compression="snappy")

spark.stop()
```

Comment: Can you step back and describe what it is you seek to do? Perhaps reading 4TBs of data into a DataFrame just to filter it is not the best approach. Perhaps you might use a database or process the files individually.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Your naive approach to merging the files is almost certain to fail due to exceeding available disk space and even if it doesn't fail in that manner it is going to take a **really long time**.

Comment: edit: Agree with above, but it may help you if you redirect loop output like `for file  .... ; do ... ;done | gzip -9 - >>$outFile`. Hmm may need a flag to tell `gzip` to read from stdin, `man gzip`. Remove the `>> $outFile` inside your loop of course. This may crash out memory, so  ... Good luck!

Comment: I'd consider using zstd for the final result, not gzip, to get better compression of the combined file.